# Android: Resize EditText when Appcomat bottomsheet shows

Tags: android, android-appcompat, bottom-sheet

I have a multiline EditText and a button, The button brings up a persistent bottom sheet (modal would not do here).

The bottomsheet is basically a LinearLayout, turned into an appcompat bottomsheet, with

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
```

in the XML.

The the buttonpress brings it up like this:

```
 View bottomSheet = context.findViewById(R.id._bottom_sheet);

 BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);

 behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
```

Now, I know it's expected behaviour, that the bottom sheet covers whatever is there (and I do not want to make it modal, for the EditText needs to retain its focus and selection, etc.), but my question is:

**Is there a way to make the bottom view resize the EditText, so that is always show "whole"?** Something like when you show a keyboard.

(***Edited***: the original question would allow for panning, which would hide the top portion of the view)

Or am I better off just turning it into a "regular" view, and make it "come up" with button click?

Thanks for your insight.

**Edit**: I also need to mention, the Bottomsheet is defined on the main activity, while the EditText is on a ViewPager in a fragment (which makes resizing less than straightforward)

Comment: Set a BottomSheetCallback to bottomSheet. You will receive callbacks when the sheet slides with a float parameter. Then translate your view based on the slide value.

Comment: @mvai  Thanks, that's a great start, now I can figure out how much of the view  is exactly covered. It also made me realise that my question was wrong, panning will only push things around, I'll really need to resize it. Still not sure how. setLayoutparams could be a solution though...

Comment: yes, change layout params to change height.

Comment: @mvai Been fiddling with it for a while, to find I was addressing the wrong resource. :) Regardless of what on the ViewPager I wanted to resize, it was the ViewPager size to change really...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was not really a problem, but a wrong approach towards solving something. The `EditText` in question was itself placed on a `ViewPager`. Resizing the `Viewpager` itself resized everything in it, and correctly resizing the `EditText`.

Thanks to m vai's comment above to direct me to this solution.